# setX() and setY() Is setting a random value instead of calculated values

Tags: android

I'm trying to move a view on the screen to set it between 2 views dynamically. Those 2 views will always change and they will have varying heights. So After getting the visible views I did the following

```
                    int[] locationForFirst = new int[2];
                    int[] locationForLast = new int[2];
                    visibleActiveViews.get(0).getLocationOnScreen(locationForFirst);
                    visibleActiveViews.get(visibleActiveViews.size() - 1).getLocationOnScreen(locationForLast);
                    Log.d("First", "x: " + locationForFirst[0] + " y: " + locationForFirst[1]);
                    Log.d("Last", "x: " + locationForLast[0] + " y: " + locationForLast[1]);
                    mBinding.leftCenterArrow.setTranslationX(locationForFirst[0]+locationForLast[0])/2);
                    mBinding.leftCenterArrow.setTranslationY((locationForFirst[1]+locationForLast[1])/2);
```

[end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJxpe.png)

end result
when the first item is at

[first item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPEO9.png)

and the last item is at

[last item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdM8q.png)

the final view should be at 464 and 846 respectively
why would it end up at some random value like that

PS: I tried setX() and setY() with the same result.

Comment: Did you try get ```getLocationInWindow()```  instead of ```getLocationOnScreen()``` and then setting x & y ?

Comment: yes, that did not work